# Python - Addings nulls

Tags: python, facebook, list, null

I currently have data coming in using the facebook api that looks like this

```
[(9, 0), (10, 0), (11, 0), (12, 0)]
[(5, 2), (6, 2), (7, 0), (8, 2), (9, 0), (10, 0), (11, 3), (12, 1)]
[(1, 1), (2, 0), (3, 1), (4, 1), (5, 0), (6, 0), (7, 0), (8, 0), (9, 0), (10, 0), (11, 1), (12, 1)]
```

Each row represents one facebook page. The first digit in a tuple represents the month, while the 2nd digit represents how many posts are on that Facebook page. 
As you can see with the first row there are no posts between January to August and also with the second you can see that there were no posts made between January and April. I want to add a null value (0, 0) for all the missing months. Is there anyway of doing this?

Comment: Actually, it seems to me that in the first case there were no posts at all. Why do you want to do this? If there's no requirement, like passing all this data to some foreign code, you might be better off not making this kind of padding (as the information's already complete).

Comment: Do you really want (0,0) or (month,0)? If (0,0) then order will be important the dict/defaultdict solutions may be problematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can with a list comprehension and lookup:

```
>>> l = [(9, 0), (10, 0), (11, 0), (12, 0)]
>>> lookup = dict(l)
>>> [(x, lookup[x]) if x in lookup else (0, 0) for x in range(1, 13)]
[(0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), 
(9, 0), (10, 0), (11, 0), (12, 0)]
```

Or to include the month:

```
>>> l = [(5, 2), (6, 2), (7, 0), (8, 2), (9, 0), (10, 0), (11, 3), (12, 1)]
>>> lookup = dict(l)
>>> [(x, lookup[x]) if x in lookup else (x, 0) for x in range(1, 13)]
[(1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 0), (4, 0), (5, 2), (6, 2), (7, 0), (8, 2), 
(9, 0), (10, 0), (11, 3), (12, 1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you can create a default list containing twelve `(0, 0)`.
Then, replace the values with present one thanks to a simple `for` loop.

```
values = [(0,0)] * 12
for value in row:
    values[value[0] - 1] = value
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use a `defaultdict`, which eliminates the need to manually set missing values, but allows to query for non existing values, too:

```
from collections import defaultdict

dict = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
list = [(5, 2), (6, 2), (7, 0), (8, 2), (9, 0), (10, 0), (11, 3), (12, 1)]

for item in list:
    dict[item[0]] = item[1]
```

Now a missing month returns `0`:

```
print(dict[4]) # ==> 0
```

Entries for missing months are created just on demand when you access them.

---

If you need or want to **stay with a list**, you could use the following list comprehension:

```
list = [(i, 0) if list[0][0] != i else list.pop(0) for i in range(1,13)]
```

This will return:

```
[(1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 0), (4, 0), (5, 2), (6, 2), (7, 0), (8, 2), (9, 0), (10, 0), (11, 3), (12, 1)]
```